# Lenovo z50-70 won't turn back on after lid closes

Tags: 16.04

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo z50-70 everything works fine except for when I close the lid of my laptop and or suspend the laptop, it doesn't turn back on. the power is still running but it's almost as if the laptop has frozen, not sure if that's the case..

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: If it has a Nvidia Graphics card you may need to install Nvidia drivers for better performance.

Comment: Does running the command `pm-suspend` make it suspend and resume properly?  If it fails, try `sudo pm-suspend` and report if it works or not.

Comment: Tried that, it freezes on that too

Comment: Try running `acpi_listen > ~/listen` in terminal.  Close the laptop for a few seconds, and open it again.  You may have to reboot, but you'll have a file in your home folder called `listen`.  Open that file and post the output of it into your question.

Comment: Hi Dorian, I did as you asked, but when I opened the file after the manual reboot it was empty